# GitLab assumes wrong username

Tags: git, gitlab, account

When I run `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` I get the message
`Welcome to GitLab, @superfake!`. "superfake" is a username I have on other services, for example github I think, and on a previous computer... But it is not the correct username for GitLab, and I don't know how they have gotten associated. When I try to fetch a repo from my own project I get the message

```
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: ERROR: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.

remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This started a few days ago, and is the case from multiple computers, it's almost spooky, but since the username "superfake" is familiar, I guess I've done something. Any insights?

**Edit**:

The spookyness is reduced when remembering that I'm using ssh agent-forwarding (-A) for most computers, so it is enough to have problem on my desktop.

An observation: on XUbuntu 22.04, when running `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` in a new terminal window the name is `@superfake` but if I open another tab, and run the command there, the name is `@superrandom`, which is the correct gitlab name, and `git fetch` works from the second tab! So there seems to be something about the environment.

After doing `env > test1` in the first terminal and `env > test2` in the second, I compared the environments with `vimdiff test1 test2` and found that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` in the firs terminal, while undefined in the other. If doing `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=` in the first terminal, I get back the correct username `superrandom`. Not sure what's going on here.

**Edit2**:
First, gnome-terminal indeed has problems with tabs having different environments, including the variables mentioned above, and I have switched to xfce-terminal (running xubunty).

Secondly, when connecting to github or gitlab, you don't actually connect using a user-name, only using the key, and if that key is valid it is associated with your username. So adding a key, lets say `key1.pub` to your gitlab user and adding

```
host *gitlab*
  identityfile ~/.ssh/key1.pub
  identitiesonly yes
```

to `~/.ssh/config` will work. Also doing `ssh-add -l` could be necessary. Otherwise some other key might be used.

Thirdly, when using agent-forwarding, an intermediate/target computer's local `.ssh/config` file will override the forwarding, so any  machines `config` file should basically only contain entries like

```
host nickname
  hostname server1
  user myname
```

for convenient access to servers, but not other fields that may contradict the forwarded agents settings to those servers.

Comment: What does git config say about who you are? What ssh identities do you have?

Comment: @matt In `.ssh/config` I have different user names for different hosts, one of which is "superfake", but I'm not using that host, on all other there are other names. There is no specific entry for gitlab or github though.

Comment: Right, that's what I suspected. I think you need that — you have to distinguish who you are by where you are, if you see what I mean. Also you can configure your `gitconfig` to use your correct email for GitHub or GitLab or whatever.

Comment: (please note that `gitconfig` name and email are for indicating who did a particular commit and have ****ABSOLUTELY NO CONNECTION WHATSOEVER**** to any part of SSH authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your ssh config file: `~/.ssh/config`. If you don't find it, create one.

For it to work should have something like this:

```
# Personal github account: superfake
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
     User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_superfake
  
# Enterprise gitlab account: superman
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
     User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_superman
```

(Note that IdentityFile points to each user's private key)

Check more here: https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/80a89405ab9023894df7

Comment: Nit: while this will work, you don't need separate keys for separate services. It's only required when using separate accounts on the same service.

Comment: And how do I connect the correct gitlab username to the public key?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've pulled a key from another system that is associated with the `superfake` GitLab account (are you certain you didn't create that in the distant past?), and your ssh-agent is trying that one first. `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` is the verbose version of that command, and it will indicate which specific identity SSH is using to connect to GitLab.

If that's the case, and you don't want to use the `superfake` account on GitLab, then you can structure your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host gitlab.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/real-key-not-superfake
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The `IdentitiesOnly` param here will instruct ssh-agent to use *only* this identity, and error out if that identity doesn't work. Without that param, ssh-agent will always try all the identities it knows.